# !empty() resulting true for value 0.0000

Tags: php, if-statement, is-empty

I came across this situation, perhaps a logical error in the code.

This is my code

```
foreach ($options as $option) {

if (($option['max_value'] > 0) && $total_value <= $option['max_value']) {
        $selected_options[] = $option['option_id'];
        continue;
    }
    if (($option['min_value'] > 0) && $total_value >= $option['min_value']) {
        $selected_options[] = $option['option_id'];
    }
}
```

This works fine. But if i replace(this is what i did earlier, so the logical error)

```
if(($option['min_value'] > 0 ) ..... ) with

if(!empty($option['min_value']) .... ) same for checking max_value.
```

But the issue is only while checking min_value

Its treating 0.0000 to be not empty so i'm not getting the expected output. Can somebody please explain me what is wrong??

$options values are coming from database, i have 2 rows

1. min_value = 0.0000 max_value = 20.0000
2. min_value = 21.0000 max_value = 0.0000

Thanks!!

Thank You all!! Its a lesson learnt!!!

Comment: What does `echo gettype($option['min_value']);` print?  `double` or `string`?

Comment: Oh!! It says String!! Why is that?? My DB field is DECIMAL(15, 4).

Comment: Depends on the API used to transfer data from and to the database.

Comment: Then how its right for > 0 condition?? That also should be false right??

Comment: There are quite some rants about the type/cast system in php. In your case your string is evaluated in a) a boolean context and and b) a numeric context. see http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must read manual about [empty](http://php.net/empty#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues)

`0.0000` is not a number it is a string.

Comment: 0.00000 can be a double, but since the source is a database it might be a string which would explain the behavior

Comment: its a float. i did read documentation. It says 0 represented in float is also 0.

Comment: We cant say 0.0000 is a string, `var_dump(0.0000);` gives an output as float(0) only.

Comment: Then how its right for > 0 condition?? That also should be false right??

Comment: @Razor, now you must look this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

`if(!empty($option['min_value']) .... )` will definitely treat it as non rempty.

According to the manual, empty() determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.

`0.0000` is a sequence of character which cannot be considered as empty.

Answer (score 0):

because the value in the variable is extracted from database so the value will be treated as a string.
And empty() will only return true if the value in the variable is 0.0 (float/numeric) or 0 (numeric) or '0' (string)
so '0.0' (string) would be returned as false.

Answer (score 0):

Just change type of float to int

empty((int)$model['product_cost']) this returns false even if the value is 0.0